# AMP exist but don't show up

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins, amp-html

(I am not a programmer)

I wanted to create AMP for my blog posts, so I performed these following steps:

1.) Installed AMP plugin by Automattic that creates AMP of current blog posts.

2.) Installed Glue for Yoast SEO & AMP , this plugin helps indexing of AMP so that AMPs can use same meta data from blog posts.

3.) Installed Facebook Instant Articles & Google AMP Pages, this is used to redesign AMPs as per our choice.

4.) After all this I installed this chrome extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amp-validator/nmoffdblmcmgeicmolmhobpoocbbmknc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

this extension is the AMP validator, it shows 4 signs for AMP pages i.e no color for pages that are not AMP, Red, blue and green. Red is meant to show errors with AMP, blue means that the page is available in AMP and clicking on blue icon takes you to AMP version, and green means the page is showing AMP version.

After I installed those 3 necessary plugins, it started showing me the blue color icon which means the page is AMP but clicking on the icon takes me to same page.

I thought that the page may not have been converted to AMP but today I got an email from Google webmaster tools saying that Google has detected there are many AMP pages on your website.

This simply means that AMPs are there but neither Google nor humans can find it. Can anyone here please help me over this. If you want to see the website then it is [here](http://www.focusandleap.com).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like AMP is generated, but for some reason page is redirected to normal version. Uninstall plugin 3 and 4, and see if it works with this address:
http://www.focusandleap.com/my-location-know-current-address/amp/

Make sure, you refreshed page cache.

Edit:
I see that you have all pages from AMP with 301 error (moved permanently).

Comment: Thanks a lot friend for your hint, your 301 error suggestion solved everything, I checked and found a setting enabled in Yoast SEO plugin which was required to be disabled. The pages are now showing AMP versions but with some errors, they are not showing content images and much more. I am getting errors like : "The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.", this is just one of those 7 errors. Any idea about this?